# Can´t calculate the sum of several bytes in Python 2.7

Tags: python, byte

I am trying to calculate the sum of several bytes in Python:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import socket
BUFFER_SIZE = 160
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect(('192.168.0.1', 1000))
data = s.recv(BUFFER_SIZE)
s.close()
print "Payload: ",data.encode("HEX")
# Payload for example 010101010101010101
print "Sum of bytes 2, 4, 8:",data[2].encode("HEX")+data[4].encode("HEX")+data[8].encode("HEX")
```

In this example I expect the result to be 0x01+0x01+0x01 = 0x03. However I just get the result of 0x010101.

How can I calculate the sum of the bytes?

Comment: Try printing the individual bytes to check what you are trying to sum

Comment: what is there inside `data[2]` and what does `type(data[2])` give you

Comment: Following @Jeril comment, i'd say you have to do `int(data[2].encode("HEX"))` for each byte

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python3:

```
print "Sum of bytes 2, 4, 8:",data[2]+data[4]+data[8]
```

Python2:

```
print "Sum of bytes 2, 4, 8:", hex(ord(data[2])+ord(data[4])+ord(data[8]))
```

Comment: Unfortunately it doesnt work.  `print "Sum of bytes 2, 4, 8:",data[2]+data[4]+data[8]` just gives the result 0x010101 but I need the sum of the bytes. In this example 0x03

Comment: Um, sorry, I gave you the answer that works for Python3, but apparently you are using Python2, which interprets elements of `bytes` as strings rather than integers. This should work for Python2: `print "Sum of bytes 2, 4, 8:", hex(ord(data[2])+ord(data[4])+ord(data[8]))`

Comment: BTW, if you need to sum up a larger chunk, like for example bytes 20 to 29, this should come handy: `hex(sum(map(ord, data[20:30])))`